# why i can not load Read only view object in the adf tester

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am work with jdeveloper 12.2.1 and when i try to run the Application Module to test the view object instances the adf tester model windows loeded but when i add a Read only view object to the adf tester and try to reload agin the adf tester model windows not load and that error appear :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq95o.png)

i searched a lot to resolve this error but no avail
any help?

Comment: the query of my view object is SELECT 
SELECT 
    USER_ROLES.USER_ROLE_ID USER_ROLE_ID, 
    USER_ROLES.USER_ID USER_ID, 
    USER_ROLES.ROLE_ID ROLE_ID, 
    USER_ROLES.CREATED_DATE CREATED_DATE, 
    USER_ROLES.LAST_UPDATED_DATE LAST_UPDATED_DATE, 
    ROLES.ROLE_ID ROLE_ID1, 
    ROLES.ROLE_EXPIRE_DATE ROLE_EXPIRE_DATE, 
    ROLES.LAST_UPDATED_DATE LAST_UPDATED_DATE1, 
    ROLES.ROLE_NAME ROLE_NAME 
FROM USER_ROLES,ROLES WHERE USER_ROLES.USER_ID = :PUSERID AND USER_ROLES.ROLE_ID = ROLES.ROLE_ID

Comment: I think that the bind variable is the problem because without this bind variable the view object is work and load in the adf tester but i can not work around this issue.so any help to work around this issue

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/message/13972650#13972650

Comment: i solved it       trustMode="trusted"

Answer (score 0):

in view object xml source change this line
trustMode="untrusted"
to 
trustMode="trusted"
and the view object will be loaded in adf model tester